# Register all sub namespace in Phalcon

Tags: phalcon, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I am new to Phalcon. The [document](https://docs.phalconphp.com/id/3.2/loader#registering-namespaces) states we can register namespace as follow

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(
[
   'Example\Base'    => 'vendor/example/base',
   'Example\Adapter' => 'vendor/example/adapter',
   'Example'         => 'vendor/example',
]);
```

It needs to register every sub namespaces under Example.
But I saw [here](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/9193/dynamic-registration-namespaces) Izo states that with suitable folder structure and namespace prefix, we only need to specific the root namespace like this

```
$loader->registerNamespaces([
  'Example'         => 'vendor/example'
])
```

Izo gave an example:
 say you have a folder directory /var/www/myapp/Plugins/,
 if you have file : /var/www/myapp/Plugins/Auth/Users.php, this file has to be 
 with namespace MYAPP\Plugins\Auth and class name has to be Users

I cannot find any document talking about it, can anyone helps?

Comment: How so? [Loader](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/loader), [Namespaces](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/namespaces), [Phalcon_Loader](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/api/Phalcon_Loader), [GitHub](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/loader.zep).

Comment: Working with namespaces in the phalcon is based on the standard 'psr 4' . Read about psr 0 and psr 4 and everything will become clear to you